# Having Trouble Loading a Pickle File

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to create a small game for fun, and I want to save and load previous run scores. I started a test file to mess around and try to figure out how pickling works. I have a pickle file with a small set of number. How do I add numbers to the pickle file and save it for the next run.

Currently I have it like this:

```
new_score = 9
filename = "scoreTest.pk"
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
infile = open(filename,'rb')
with infile as f:
    scores = pickle.load(f)
scores.add(new_score)
pickle.dump(scores, outfile)
```

When I run it like this I get this error:

```
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

If someone could please tell me what is wrong and how to do it correctly that would be great. Apologies for any un-optimal code, I'm new to code.

Comment: Where did `infile` come from?

Comment: Sound like a truncated file. Did you close it properly after writing?

Comment: `with infile as f:` isn't a thing. Can you post a running example? You'll get that error is the file is empty. So figuring out how it was created really helps.

Comment: @Craig I have edited the original code, my bad.

Comment: @tdelaney I was using infile as a variable and forgot to add it, it is there now.

Comment: @KlausD. That may be the issue, how do I properly close it.

Comment: `open(filename,'wb')` will [truncate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) your file to zero bytes! Open files when you need them only. Never open them for reading and writing at the same time. If possible use open file with a `with` block. It will close it automatically.

Comment: You could `import os` then `print(os.stat(filename).st_size` to see the size. If its zero, that's your problem. But its pretty much guaranteed to be zero because you did `outfile = open(filename,'wb')` on it.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes! That worked, a website said to do it that way and I believed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you, using the a variable to open the file was the issue. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to juggle a reader and writer on the same file at the same time. The `open(filename, 'wb')` of the write deletes whatever happened to be in the file so there is no data for the reader. You should only open the file when you really need to use it. And its better to write to a temporary file and rename it. If something goes wrong you haven't lost your data.

```
import pickle
import os

new_score = 9
filename = "scoreTest.pk"
tmp_filename = "scoreTest.tmp"
try:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        scores = pickle.load(f)
except (IOError, EOFError) as e:
    scores = default # whatever that is
scores.add(new_score)
with open(tmp_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
    pickle.dump(scores, outfile)
os.rename(tmp_filename, filename)
```